# How to extract data from api function with a promise in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im using react-redux, and in my saga file where I have implemented logic for new/edit page, I need to implement an API for getting some codes for customer.

```
const getCodesById = (Id) => get(`${BASE_URL}/${companyId}/codes`);

export function* getTableById(action) {

    const Id = yield select(getCurrentCustomeId);
    getEarningCodesForCompany(companyId).then((response) => {
        console.log(response) //It shows correct array of objects from api  
        return response;
        });
}
```

in `console.log(response)` I can see the data properly.
However, I dont know how can I extract that response in some variable outside that function to be able to use it along in the function `getTableById`.

I tried with  `const request = yield call(getCodesById(Id));` but with yield my program is crashing.

How can I do this to, get response and use it elsewhere?

Comment: Can you share your code with codesandbox or stackblitz or even github?, You should be able to use `yield call` to get response and store to redux reducer to use in anywhere you want with `yield put`. So I think should be your saga configure problem. Please kindly share your all codes that have minimum logic and your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function* getTableById(action) {
    const Id = yield select(getCurrentCustomeId);
    const codes = yield call(getEarningCodesForCompany, companyId);
    console.log(codes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a return statement before getEarningCodesForCompany:

```
const getCodesById = (Id) => get(`${BASE_URL}/${companyId}/codes`);

export function* getTableById(action) {

const Id = yield select(getCurrentCustomeId);
return getEarningCodesForCompany(companyId).then((response) => {
    console.log(response) //It shows correct array of objects from api  
    return response;
    });
}
```